# Why does >= operator work as > operator in C when compared with 0.9

Tags: c, if-statement, floating-point, precision

I was working with C and tried this :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     float b=0.8,a=0.6;
     if(a&&b>=0.8)
     printf("\nclass")  ;
     else
     printf("\nb");
     return 0;
}
```

And the output came :-

```
class
```

But when I changed the value of b to 0.9 and expression in if to a&&b>=0.9 :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     float b=0.9,a=0.6;
     if(a&&b>=0.9)
     printf("\nclass")  ;
     else
     printf("\nb");
     return 0;
}
```

then output was:-

```
b
```

Can anyone explain why >= operator started to act as > operator when the value of b was 0.9 ?

Thanks in advance.

Something to add as some guys think I am wasting their time :-
I also tried to debug it as :-

```
    #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
float b=0.9,a=0.6;
printf(" int a   -   %d\n", (int)a);
printf("int b -    %d\n", (int)b);
printf("a&&b  -   %d\n", a&&b);
printf("b>=0.9  -  %d\n", b>=0.9);
if(a&&b>=0.9)
printf("\nclass");
else
printf("\nb");
return 0;   
}
```

Now the O/p was :-

```
int a   -   0
int b -    0
a&&b  -   1
b>=0.9  -  0
```

Now please that "Precedence Guy" tell me what order of precedence would be followed in a single >= operator.

Comment: what do you think `&&` does in your program?

Comment: On your machine `(float) 0.9f` is not as great as `(double) 0.9`.  Both are approximations of 0.9, but since being binary representations, fail to be exact.  The `double 0.9` is closer to mathematical 0.9 and different than `(float) 0.9f`.  It is a coin flip in that `double 0.9` is greater than `(float) 0.9f`.

Comment: The nearest to 0.9 in double precision is 0.90000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625 but 0.89999997615814208984375 in single precision. Truncating the double value to float results in a value not closest to 0.9f. And `a&&b>=0.9` doesn't mean that "both a and b are larger or equal to 0.9"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
double x1 = 0.9;
float xf = (float)x1; // discard some precision
double x2 = (double)xf;

if (x2 >= x1) {
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that, after you discarded some precision from `x1` by converting it to `float`, it can never be recovered; casting it back to `double` doesn't regain that precision. So `x2` is still not the same as `0.9`, and due to the rounding direction, it happens to be a bit less. (Note: if you try the same thing with other values, you will sometimes find that it's a bit *more*.)

Answer (score 0):

`0.9` can't be exactly represented in binary .

And also importantly `0.9(being double)` is first implicitly converted to `float(less precesion)` and then converted back to double(`higher precession than float`) does no remain excalty `0.9`.

Therefore, the value of `b` is apporximately close to `0.9` not equal to `0.9`. Therefore ,you get `b`.

Comment: I.e. equality might not work when you're using floating point numbers.

Comment: @che Yes , that's correct .

Comment: -1, sorry. It's true that `0.9` can't be exactly represented in binary, but the important point here is the conversion to `float` and back. Had the OP used `double` instead, (s)he would have seen the behavior (s)he expected.

Comment: @ruakh  Implicit conversion . Ahh , I overlooked it . Thanks for correcting me . I shall correct it .

Comment: @che why? it is working for all numbers except 0.9....whats so special in 0.9?

Comment: @ruakh But why does implicit conversion not affect the result in any other number except 0.9?

Comment: @dknight "it is working for all numbers except 0.9"? How many of the 18 quintillion `double` did you try?

Comment: @dknight: I'm sure you haven't tried all numbers. There are most probably more that don't work, you just haven't stumbled onto them. It's a matter of how they're stored in binary.

Comment: @chux yeah I didn't try all the numbers but still why are there such exceptions?

Comment: @che please convert 0.8 into binary...it is also a never ending binary number like 0.9 but >= works correctly there? Why is it so?

0.9= 0.111001100110...
0.8= 0.110011001100...

Comment: @dknight: If you change the `>=` to `==` (so as to detect roundoff error in *either* direction), you'll observe this behavior for 0.8 as well.

Comment: @dknight it's not exception. It happens every time. Read http://floating-point-gui.de/ and [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). And there's no way for you to test for all possible double values in this universe's time.

Comment: thanks all...That solved it .

Comment: @dknight: Uh, ok. 0.8 is "\x9a\x99\x99\x99\x99\x99\xe9\x3f", 0.9 is "\xcd\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xed\x3f". 0.8 converted to float and back to double is "\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x99\x99\e9\x3f".

Answer (score 0):

Computers only know binary representation. It is able to represent decimal numbers in binary without a problem(and that changes with extremely large numbers too), but when it comes to fractional numbers it is not able to fully represent the number.

In binary each number is multiplied with 2 instead of 10 in decimal.

For example look at number 13

1*10^1 + 3*10^0

to represent the same number in binary system we need

1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 0*2^1 + 1*2^0 = (1101)

But things get complicated at fractional parts.
Again with an example:

13.26 = 13 + 2/10^1 + 6/10^2

but in binary

(1101) + 0/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 0/2^3 + 0/2^4 + 0/2^5 + 0/2^6 + 1/2^7 + 0/2^8 + 1/2^9 + ... = (1101.010000101....)

I hope this shows that it's not that easy to represent a fractional number with limited space.

Now, as soon as you declare your variables as floats, there's a limited space allocated for them and computer barely gets close to that fractional number. In the if condition you don't specify a type and compiler automatically chooses double over float which has more space and can represent the fractional number more accurately. In one case float represents the number bigger and in the other one it represents the number as smaller.

To fix that you can convert the literal to a float

```
float b = 0.9, a = 0.6;
if (a&&b >= (float)0.9)
    printf("\nclass");
else
    printf("\nb");
cin.get();
return 0;
```

which will output

> \nclass